# List File in each subdirectory ONLY if older than x days

Tags: powershell

I trying to get a list of files that meet the following criteria:

for each subdirectory:
sort files in descending order (most recent first)
get the first record (the oldest file)
if it's older than x days, then append filename to csv file

I found this code on [PowerShell.org](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/return-date-of-most-recently-modified-file-in-each-sub-dir/) and it does 90% of what I'm trying to accomplish.  I need to change the code to add an if the current object is over x days then AND ONLY then write it to the csv file.  Here's the code:

```
$projectsFolder = 'Z:\CSDataBU'
$resultsPath = 'D:\oldFiles.csv'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $projectsFolder -Directory -Force | ForEach-Object {

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File -Recurse -Force | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    } | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Property Name,LastWriteTime,FullName | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $resultsPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Where-Object` condition that checks the age of the `LastWriteTime`. Here we are looking for files last changed more than 30 days ago.

```
$MinimumAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Select-Object -Property Name,LastWriteTime,FullName |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $MinimumAge}
```